# Path prefixes \??\ and \\?\

Tags: windows, winapi, batch-file, cmd

What is the difference between paths prefixed with `\??\` and those prefixed with `\\?\`

At Windows 7 CMD-Line

- DIR gives:             `\??\Volume{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\`
- WMIC VOLUME LIST gives `\\?\Volume{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\`

Thanks

Additional Information:
I created a directory on my system drive where i placed all my mount points into. So I did a `MD C:\HDDs` first, then a 
`MD C:\HDD\Drive1`, `MD C:\HDD\Drive2` ...for all my drives. After mounting the drives on those empty directories, I can see the GUID by switching to that Directory with `CD /D C:\HDDs` and issueing a `DIR` command.  Maybe I have to issue a `DIR /ah` to Show hidden stuff, just in case the mount points are hidden directories ...

Comment: Not off-topic.  Only of interest to programmers.

Comment: What's the context? \?? is a NT Object Manager path and \\? is the raw path notation used to bypass path length limits/expansion

Comment: @AlexK.: I believe that's `\\.\ ` not `\\?\ ` ?

Comment: \\?\ is the "raw path" for the file system, \\.\ is the same but for device paths

Comment: Just for my own sanity - I can't get the device ID from `dir`, and can't see an option to do so (or I'm blind). How have you got that?

Comment: @Chris:  Just edited my question so you may see how I got the device ID with `DIR`. Of course, if you make a `DIR` where there is no drive mounted you will not see any device information.  But I assume you knew that already ;-)

Comment: Related question on SuperUser sister site: [What does \??\ mean in \??\C:\Windows\System32\conhost.exe?](https://superuser.com/q/810609/907663). Also, Microsoft doc for the "\\.\" and "\\?\" prefixes: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In NT, `\??\` is a path prefix that stands for the object directory that's reserved for devices, or more specifically, device aliases (made available to the Win32 subsystem/personality). A device alias is implemented in the object namespace as a symbolic link (not to be confused with the file system entity of the same name) that typically resolves to a device object in the `\Device` directory. Sometimes in the documentation these device aliases are referred to as "junctions" in the object namespace, which is not to be confused with "directory junctions" (or mount points) in a file system.

Using the `\??\` prefix instructs the object manager to search in the caller's *session-local* device directory, `\Sessions\0\DosDevices\[Logon Authentication ID`, which is coupled to (i.e. shadows) the global device directory, `\GLOBAL??`. For efficiency, both of these directories are cached by an access token's associated logon-session record and also by each process object. The SYSTEM logon (ID 0x3E7) uses `\GLOBAL??` as its local device directory. Note that the local directory has a `Global` link -- back to `\GLOBAL??` -- to allow accessing global devices when a local device shadows the global one (e.g. `\??\Global\Z:`), or to allow a device driver to create a global device when not executing in a SYSTEM thread. NT originally used a single `\DosDevices` directory, regardless of the caller. With the introduction of Terminal Services and fast-user switching between NT 4 and XP, they had to generalize it to the present system of local and global devices. Nowadays, for backwards compatibility, `\DosDevices` is a symbolic link to `\??`.

Translating DOS paths to native NT paths is implemented by NT's user-mode runtime library (i.e. the `Rtl` prefixed functions that are exported by `ntdll.dll`).

The straight-forward case is a path that's prefixed by either `\\.\` or `\\?\`. This is a [*local device path*](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file), not a UNC path. (Strictly speaking it's in the form of a UNC path, but "." and "?" are reserved device domains.) For this case, the prefix is simply replaced by NT `\??`. The difference between the two Win32 API device path prefixes is that a `\\?\` path (all backslashes, no forward slashes) is a so-called "extended" path, which bypasses all normalization, whereas a `\\.\` path gets normalized.

Device path normalization resolves "." and ".." components, replaces forward slashes with backslashes, and strips trailing spaces and dots from the final path component. Because forward slashes are translated to backslashes, the prefix of a normalized device path can be `//./` or `//?/` or any combination of slashes and backslashes, except for exactly `\\?\`. Note that if the process doesn't support long paths, normalized paths are limited to less than `MAX_PATH` (260) characters. (Long-path support can be enabled in Windows 10 through a combination of registry and application manifest settings; consult the relevant documentation.) [`GetFullPathNameW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfullpathnamew) handles both prefixes equivalently and even normalizes an extended path that begins with `\\?\`.

UNC paths are also unsurprising. The runtime library simply replaces the leading `\\?` in the normalized path with an explicit reference to the `UNC` device, i.e. `\??\UNC\` (e.g. `\\server\share` -> `\??\UNC\server\share`). Note that `\GLOBAL??\UNC` is a symbolic link to `\Device\Mup`, the Multiple UNC Provider device, which is responsible for mapping the `\\server\share` to the correct UNC provider (e.g. to the `LanmanWorkstation` redirector for an SMB share).

DOS drive paths (i.e. those beginning with an "[A-Z]:" drive) are interesting in a couple of cases. The first is that the runtime library supports per-drive working directories using conventionally 'hidden' environment variables such as `=C:`. For example, `C:System32` resolves to `C:\Windows\System32` if the "=C:" environment variable is set to `C:\Windows`. Also, if the last component of the path is a reserved DOS device name, including if the name has trailing colons, spaces, dots, and even a file extension, the path gets translated to a device path (e.g. `C:\Windows\nul: .txt` -> `\??\NUL`). (DOS devices are also reserved in the final component of relative paths that have no drive.) Otherwise, the runtime library simply prepends `\??\` to the normalized path (e.g. `C:/Windows` -> `\??\C:\Windows`).

A DOS drive such as `C:` (i.e. `\GLOBAL??\C:`) is an alias for an NT volume device (i.e. an object symbolic link). The NT device name is not persistent and is typically enumerated, so the final target depends on the relative order in which volumes are added, and it may even change if a volume is removed and subsequently restored. For example, the final NT path for `E:\Temp` on a removable drive may start out as `\Device\HarddiskVolume8\Temp` and then, after removing and reinserting it, the new final path is `\Device\HarddiskVolume10\Temp`. The mount-point manager implements persistence using the unique ID of a volume, which it associates with a volume GUID name (e.g. `Volume{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`) and optionally (usually) a DOS drive letter. The GUID name is used to implement volume mount points in file systems that support junctions (i.e. `IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT` [reparse points](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/fileio/reparse-points)), such as NTFS and ReFS.

Further reading: [The Definitive Guide on Win32 to NT Path Conversion](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2016/02/the-definitive-guide-on-win32-to-nt.html).

Hint: Use a tool such as [WinObj](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/winobj) to investigate the NT object manager namespace yourself.

Comment: There are a way to create a directory junctions with the \??\ junction? For example, instead of mount a volume, create a symlink to `\??\Volume{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\MyFolderTarget`.

Comment: @Zano, It is possible to create both a junction and a symlink, with \\?\ prefix (but not \??\). Even built-in mklink can do it. But expect issues with various software that still lack support of such entities (for example, Python).

Comment: @BasilPeace technically both should work. AFAIK `\\?` is in most scenarios involving file system interchangeable with `\??`. Why is easy to explain: `\\?` appears to be a concept of the Win32 layer, but `\??` are NT native paths. Also, do you mean the link target, or the link name? Btw, have you tried your claim? Because `mklink /d foobar \??\Volume{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` works on W10 (10.0.19045). But then, `mklink` may even enforce stricter checking than the underlying OS functionality would; so I don't know where you take your info from. Any sources? Thanks!

Comment: @0xC0000022L, is it working, if you use real volume UUID? `cd foobar` gives me an error

Comment: Also, if you're linking a volume's root directory, trailing backslash is required. Otherwise, it doesn't work too. I agree, my claims are dubious. `mklink` may *work* but not create anything working. I should've said "create and use".

Comment: @BasilPeace Fair point, whether it's usable depends on the object manager and the file system driver which interact to make reparse points work.