# WriteFile and ReadFile on child process's stdio (using overlapped named pipe)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, process, io-redirection

I want to read asynchronously from a child process's stdin, so I create an IOCP loop that listens for when `ReadFile()` is done. But `ReadFile()` is never done, it always returns `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, and `WriteFile()` always returns `ERROR_IO_PENDING`.

Node.js can asynchronously read from a child process:

```js
const child_process = require("child_process")

var p = child_process.spawn("gcc")

p.stdout.on('data', data=>console.log(String(data)))

p.stderr.on('data', data=>console.log(String(data)))
```

How to do this in the Win32 API?

```c
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <assert.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "User32.lib")

static HANDLE iocp = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

typedef struct PROCESS {
    OVERLAPPED ol;
    HANDLE hProcess,
      stdin_read, stdin_write,
      stdout_read, stdout_write,
      stderr_read, stderr_write;
    char buf[100];
} PROCESS, *PPROCESS, *LPROCESS;

DWORD WINAPI Worker(LPVOID param);

BOOL create_pipe(HANDLE* pserver_pipe, HANDLE* pclient_pipe, PROCESS* p) {
    static __int64 counter=0;
    HANDLE server_pipe, client_pipe;
    int err;
    WCHAR name[64];
    for (;;) {
        swprintf(name, sizeof(name), L"\\\\?\\pipe\\child\\%Id.%p", counter, p);
        server_pipe = CreateNamedPipeW(
            name,
            PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE | WRITE_DAC,
            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT, 
            1, 
            65536, 
            65536, 
            0,
            NULL);
        if (server_pipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            break;
        err = GetLastError();
        if (err != ERROR_PIPE_BUSY && err != ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof sa;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = 1;
    client_pipe = CreateFileW(name,
                            GENERIC_READ|WRITE_DAC,
                            0,
                            &sa,
                            OPEN_EXISTING,
                            FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                            NULL);
    if (client_pipe==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (CreateIoCompletionPort(client_pipe, iocp, (ULONG_PTR)p, 0)==NULL){
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (CreateIoCompletionPort(server_pipe, iocp, (ULONG_PTR)p, 0)==NULL){
        return FALSE;
    }
    *pclient_pipe = client_pipe;
    *pserver_pipe = server_pipe;
    return TRUE;
}

int wmain() 
{    
    iocp = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0);
    assert(iocp);
    PROCESS child_process{};
 
    assert(create_pipe(&child_process.stdout_write, &child_process.stdout_read, &child_process));
    assert(create_pipe(&child_process.stderr_write, &child_process.stderr_read, &child_process));
    assert(create_pipe(&child_process.stdin_write, &child_process.stdin_read, &child_process));
 
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Worker, iocp, 0, NULL);
    assert(hThread);
 
    WCHAR szCmdline[]=L"cmd";
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo{}; 
 
    STARTUPINFOW siStartInfo{.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO), 
       .dwFlags=STARTF_USESTDHANDLES, 
       .hStdInput=child_process.stdin_read, 
       .hStdOutput=child_process.stdout_write,
       .hStdError=child_process.stderr_write};
    
    assert(CreateProcessW(NULL, szCmdline, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &siStartInfo, &piProcInfo));
    CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
//  CloseHandle(child_process.stdout_write);
//  CloseHandle(child_process.stdin_read);
    ReadFile(child_process.stdout_read, child_process.buf, sizeof(child_process.buf), NULL, &child_process.ol);

    int err = GetLastError();

    if (err!=ERROR_IO_PENDING){
        printf("Error in ReadFile %d\n", err);
    }else{
        puts("ReadFile is pending...\n");
    }
    char buf[100];
    DWORD dwIn;
    for(;;){
        ReadConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), buf, sizeof buf, &dwIn, NULL);
        if (dwIn<=0)
            break;
        WriteFile(child_process.stdin_write, buf, dwIn, NULL, &child_process.ol);
        err = GetLastError();
        if (err!=ERROR_IO_PENDING){
            printf("Error in WriteFile %d\n", err);
        }else{
            puts("WriteFile is pending...\n");
        }
    }
    PostQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp, 0, 0, 0);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
    CloseHandle(iocp);
}

DWORD WINAPI Worker(LPVOID param) {
    DWORD dwIoSize = 0;
    LPOVERLAPPED ol;
    PROCESS* ctx;
    for(;;){
        BOOL bSuccess = GetQueuedCompletionStatus((HANDLE)param, &dwIoSize,
            (PDWORD_PTR)&ctx,
            &ol,
            INFINITE);
        if (ctx == NULL) {
            printf("ctx is NULL, maybe you call PostQueuedCompletionStatus? err=%d\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }
        if (bSuccess==FALSE || dwIoSize == 0) {
            printf("GetQueuedCompletionStatus does not success(maybe EOF reached?) err=%d\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }
        WriteConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ctx->buf, dwIoSize, NULL, NULL);
        ReadFile(ctx->stdout_read, ctx->buf, sizeof(ctx->buf), NULL, &ctx->ol);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I create a IOCP loop* - not need. use better `BindIoCompletionCallback` or `CreateThreadpoolIo` and let system do this part of job for you

Comment: You can't use the same `OVERLAPPED` instance for multiple I/O operations that are running at the same time.  Your `ReadFile()` and `WriteFile()` are sharing `child_process.ol`. You need to dynamically allocate a new `OVERLAPPED` for each operation, and then have your worker thread free each `OVERLAPPED` that comes out of the IOCP queue

Comment: yes, but only ReadFile doesn’t work, too

Comment: `\\?\pipe\child\<Id>.<p>` is not a valid name for a named pipe. A pipe name must be in `\\<ServerName>\pipe\<PipeName>` format, where the *ServerName* cannot be `?` (the ```\\?\``` prefix is for UNC paths), and the *PipeName* cannot contain a ```\``` character. This is clearly outlined in the [Pipe Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/pipe-names) documentation. Try something more like `\\.\pipe\child_%Id.%p` instead.

Comment: I leaned from [libuv](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/deps/uv/src/win/pipe.c) * uv_unique_pipe_name*

Comment: `\\.\pipe\child_%Id.%p` not work, too

Comment: @ianfun "*I leaned from libuv*" - what libuv is doing is in clear violation of Microsoft's documentation.

Comment: Your `create_pipe()` should not associate both pipe ends with the IOCP queue. Only the handle used for local I/O should be in the IOCP,, the handle inherited by the child process for remote I/O should be closed after `CreateProcess()` exits, as explained in Microsoft's documentation: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output). All you are doing is substituting `CreatePipe()` with `create_pipe()` to gain `OVERLAPPED` support. The handle management doesn't change.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `\\?\pipe` is valid.see [nodejs documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/net.html#identifying-paths-for-ipc-connections)

Comment: @ianfun AFAIK, *nowhere* does **Microsoft's** documentation say that `\\?\pipe` is valid. Everything I've found about what Microsoft says about pipes refers only to `\\.\pipe` or `\\[host]\pipe`. Outside of the libuv and Node.js links mentioned here, the only other reference to `\\?\pipe` I can find is [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279971/#comment75638240_44297917). But it doesn't matter, because Microsoft's docs are very explicit that ONLY `\\.\pipe` and `\\[host]\pipe` are supported, thus `\\?\pipe` is breaking the contract, so it shouldn't be used even if it "works".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search on Github, it's quite easy.
Create a Named Pipe for current process(read), and create a File for child process(write).

Github links:

https://github.com/parasol-framework/parasol/blob/c5ad64188c7496e3ff54eb75fd03c9e3124fe08b/src/core/microsoft/processes.c

https://github.com/dinamsky/malware-botnets/blob/4cd142d10f971cb93c334b6f48c12c85bcc8f63a/Phatbot-stoney/Phatbot-stoney/cmdshell.cpp

https://github.com/grimjoey/jlstudio/blob/e5d2d81f0a94d2020f2e912e43a487d9cb6f7c33/src/jls/process.cpp

https://github.com/Ai-Thinker-Open/Ai-Thinker-Open_ESP32-S2_SDK/blob/7d75213674b4572f90c68162ad6fe9b16dae65ad/tools/windows/tool_setup/cmdlinerunner/cmdlinerunner.c

https://github.com/LeonColt/skripsi/blob/141af593ec65cd7adaedf7a90fc4cd7cde5cc602/Maschinen/RedirectIOChildProcess.cpp

### redirect stdout and stderr

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Stdio;

typedef void (*Callback)(struct Stdio* self, DWORD len);

struct Stdio {
    OVERLAPPED ol;
    HANDLE pipe;
    BYTE buf[100];
    Callback callback;
};

typedef struct CTX {
    struct Stdio Stdout, Stderr, Stdin;
} CTX, *LCTX, *LPCTX;

HANDLE Hstdout=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
HANDLE Hstderr=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

DWORD WINAPI Worker(LPVOID iocp){
    struct Stdio *stdio;
    OVERLAPPED *ol;
    DWORD dwIoSize;
    for(;;){
        if (!GetQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp, &dwIoSize, (PDWORD_PTR)&stdio, &ol, INFINITE) || dwIoSize==0 || ol==NULL || stdio==NULL){
            switch (GetLastError()){
                case ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE:
                    puts("the process has been exited, exit thread...");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("error = %d, exit thread\n", GetLastError());
            }
            break;
        }
        stdio->callback(stdio, dwIoSize);
    }
    return 0;
}
void OnStdoutRead(struct Stdio *self, DWORD len){
    WriteConsoleA(Hstdout, self->buf, len, NULL, NULL);
    ReadFile(self->pipe, self->buf, sizeof(self->buf), NULL, &self->ol);
}
void OnStderrRead(struct Stdio *self, DWORD len){
    WriteConsoleA(Hstderr, self->buf, len, NULL, NULL);
    ReadFile(self->pipe, self->buf, sizeof(self->buf), NULL, &self->ol);
}

int wmain(){
    assert(Hstdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE));
    assert(Hstderr = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE));
    HANDLE Pstdout, Pstderr; // child process's
    CTX ctx{.Stdout=Stdio{.callback=OnStdoutRead}, .Stderr=Stdio{.callback=OnStderrRead}};

    HANDLE iocp = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0);
    HANDLE hThread =  CreateThread(NULL, 0, Worker, iocp, 0, NULL); // Worker thread

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa{.nLength=sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), .bInheritHandle=TRUE};

    const WCHAR* pipe_name1 = L"\\\\.\\Pipe\\child-1";

    assert((ctx.Stdout.pipe = CreateNamedPipeW(
        pipe_name1,
        PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE,
        1,
        4096,
        4096,
        5000,
        NULL))!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    assert(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != (Pstdout = CreateFileW(
        pipe_name1,
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        &sa,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL)));

    const WCHAR *pipe_name2 = L"\\\\.\\Pipe\\child-2";

    assert((ctx.Stderr.pipe = CreateNamedPipeW(
        pipe_name2,
        PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE,
        1,
        4096,
        4096,
        5000,
        NULL))!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    assert((Pstderr = CreateFileW(
        pipe_name2,
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        &sa,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL))!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    STARTUPINFOW si{.cb = sizeof(si), 
        .dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW, 
        .wShowWindow = SW_HIDE, 
        .hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), // use current stdin
        .hStdOutput = Pstdout, 
        .hStdError = Pstderr};

    WCHAR cmd[] = L"powershell"; // or cmd, py, bash...
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo{};

    assert(CreateProcessW(
        NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL,
        TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL,
        &si, &pInfo));

    assert(CloseHandle(Pstdout)); // we don't need this
    assert(CloseHandle(Pstderr)); // we don't need this

    assert(CreateIoCompletionPort(ctx.Stdout.pipe, iocp, (ULONG_PTR)&ctx.Stdout, 0));
    assert(CreateIoCompletionPort(ctx.Stderr.pipe, iocp, (ULONG_PTR)&ctx.Stderr, 0));

    ReadFile(ctx.Stdout.pipe, ctx.Stdout.buf, sizeof(ctx.Stdout.buf), NULL, &ctx.Stdout.ol);
    ReadFile(ctx.Stderr.pipe, ctx.Stdout.buf, sizeof(ctx.Stderr.buf), NULL, &ctx.Stderr.ol);

    WaitForSingleObject(pInfo.hProcess, INFINITE); // wait for process exit
    PostQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp, 0, 0, NULL); // tell IOCP Worker exit
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE); // wait for thread exit

    assert(CloseHandle(hThread));
    assert(CloseHandle(ctx.Stderr.pipe));
    assert(CloseHandle(ctx.Stdout.pipe));
    assert(CloseHandle(pInfo.hProcess));
    assert(CloseHandle(iocp));
    assert(CloseHandle(Hstderr));
    puts("exit main function..."); // !!important: before close stdout
    assert(CloseHandle(Hstdout));
}
```

### Redirect stdin, stdout, stderr

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static HANDLE Hstdout, Hstderr, Hstdin, HstopEvent;

struct Stdio;

typedef void (*Callback)(struct Stdio* self, DWORD len);

struct Stdio {
    OVERLAPPED ol;
    HANDLE pipe;
    BYTE buf[100];
    Callback callback;
};

typedef struct CTX {
    struct Stdio Stdout, Stderr, Stdin;
} CTX, *LCTX, *LPCTX;

DWORD WINAPI Worker(LPVOID iocp){
    struct Stdio *stdio;
    OVERLAPPED *ol;
    DWORD dwIoSize;
    for(;;){
        if (!GetQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp, &dwIoSize, (PDWORD_PTR)&stdio, &ol, INFINITE) || dwIoSize==0 || ol==NULL || stdio==NULL){
            switch (GetLastError()){
                case ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE:
                    SetEvent(HstopEvent);
                    puts("the process has been exited, exit thread...");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("error = %d, exit thread\n", GetLastError());
            }
            break;
        }
        stdio->callback(stdio, dwIoSize);
    }
    return 0;
}
void OnStdoutRead(struct Stdio *self, DWORD len){
    WriteConsoleA(Hstdout, self->buf, len, NULL, NULL);
    ReadFile(self->pipe, self->buf, sizeof(self->buf), NULL, &self->ol);
}
void OnStderrRead(struct Stdio *self, DWORD len){
    WriteConsoleA(Hstderr, self->buf, len, NULL, NULL);
    ReadFile(self->pipe, self->buf, sizeof(self->buf), NULL, &self->ol);
}
void OnStdinWriteComplete(struct Stdio *self, DWORD len){
    printf("[%u bytes write to stdin]\n", len);
}
int wmain(){
    assert((Hstdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE))!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    assert((Hstderr = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE))!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    assert((Hstdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE))!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    assert((HstopEvent=CreateEventW(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL))!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    CTX ctx{.Stdout=Stdio{.callback=OnStdoutRead}, .Stderr=Stdio{.callback=OnStderrRead}, .Stdin=Stdio{.callback=OnStdinWriteComplete}};
    STARTUPINFOW si{.cb = sizeof(si), .dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES};
    HANDLE iocp = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0);
    HANDLE hThread =  CreateThread(NULL, 0, Worker, iocp, 0, NULL); // Worker thread

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa{.nLength=sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), .bInheritHandle=TRUE};

    const WCHAR* pipe_name1 = L"\\\\.\\Pipe\\child-1";

    assert((ctx.Stdout.pipe = CreateNamedPipeW(
        pipe_name1,
        PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE,
        1,
        4096,
        4096,
        5000,
        NULL))!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    assert((si.hStdOutput = CreateFileW(
        pipe_name1,
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        &sa,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL))!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    const WCHAR *pipe_name2 = L"\\\\.\\Pipe\\child-2";

    assert((ctx.Stderr.pipe = CreateNamedPipeW(
        pipe_name2,
        PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE,
        1,
        4096,
        4096,
        5000,
        NULL))!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    assert((si.hStdError = CreateFileW(
        pipe_name2,
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        &sa,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL))!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    const WCHAR *pipe_name3 = L"\\\\.\\Pipe\\child-3";

    assert((ctx.Stdin.pipe = CreateNamedPipeW(
        pipe_name3,
        PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE,
        1,
        4096,
        4096,
        5000,
        NULL))!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    assert((si.hStdInput = CreateFileW(
        pipe_name3,
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        &sa,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL))!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    WCHAR cmd[] = L"powershell"; // or cmd, py, bash...

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo{};
    assert(CreateProcessW(
        NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL,
        TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL,
        &si, &pInfo));

    assert(CloseHandle(si.hStdError)); // we don't need this
    assert(CloseHandle(si.hStdInput)); // we don't need this
    assert(CloseHandle(si.hStdOutput)); // we don't need this
    assert(CreateIoCompletionPort(ctx.Stdout.pipe, iocp, (ULONG_PTR)&ctx.Stdout, 0));
    assert(CreateIoCompletionPort(ctx.Stderr.pipe, iocp, (ULONG_PTR)&ctx.Stderr, 0));

    ReadFile(ctx.Stdout.pipe, ctx.Stdout.buf, sizeof(ctx.Stdout.buf), NULL, &ctx.Stdout.ol);
    ReadFile(ctx.Stderr.pipe, ctx.Stdout.buf, sizeof(ctx.Stderr.buf), NULL, &ctx.Stderr.ol);
    
    DWORD dwIoSize;
    for(;;){
        CHAR buf[100];
        ReadConsoleA(Hstdin, buf, sizeof(buf), &dwIoSize, NULL);
        if (WaitForSingleObject(HstopEvent, 0)==WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            break;
        WriteFile(ctx.Stdin.pipe, buf, dwIoSize, NULL, &ctx.Stdin.ol);
        if (WaitForSingleObject(HstopEvent, 0)==WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            break;
    }
    PostQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp, 0, 0, NULL); // tell IOCP Worker exit
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE); // wait for thread exit

    assert(CloseHandle(hThread));
    assert(CloseHandle(ctx.Stderr.pipe));
    assert(CloseHandle(ctx.Stdout.pipe));
    assert(CloseHandle(pInfo.hProcess));
    assert(CloseHandle(iocp));
    assert(CloseHandle(Hstderr));
    assert(CloseHandle(HstopEvent));
    puts("exit main function..."); // !!important: before close stdout
    assert(CloseHandle(Hstdout));
}
```

Comment: some people use `select` function, but `select` requires timeout, and it’s synchronous.

Comment: Read from stdin is synchronous, so the child process might exit before we press `ENTER`.I don't known why *write to child process's stdin* never effect IOCP, the write call back `OnStdinWriteComplete` never called.